# ApplicationException not being thrown to catch block properly

Tags: c#, exception, linq-to-sql

I am having an issue where I override the `OnValidate` method of a LINQ to SQL class.  I have written my business rules properly and all is well, but when I go to catch the exception in the call to my repository, the application is treating the Exception as unhandled.

In the LINQ to SQL partial class I have the following:

```
    partial void OnValidate(ChangeAction action)
    {
        if (!IsValid)
            //Application is halting here before my catch block code is reached
            throw new ApplicationException("Invalid note data recieved!  Correct the following issues and try again:");
        //UpdateTimeStamp();
    }
```

The `IsValid` is just a set of checks on the LINQ to SQL class properties.

In my Form I have a button click event that calls the `SubmitChanges` method on my repository class.  I have wrapped it in a `try/catch` block but the Exception will not bubble up to my `catch` instead it errors at the `throw new ApplicationException()` block in my partial class.

Here is the code around the Button:  (`Repository` is an injected implementation of an `IRepository`).

```
    private void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsNewNote)
            {
                //CurrentNote is an instance of my LINQ to SQL class.
                this.Repository.InsertNote(CurrentNote);
            }
            this.Repository.Save();
        }
        catch (ApplicationException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("{0}" + Environment.NewLine + "{1}", ex.Message, this.CurrentNote.GetRuleViolations().FirstOrDefault().ErrorMessage));
        }
    }
```

And for context here are the `InsertNote()` and `Save()` methods on my repository implementation (nothing special, just basic LINQ to SQL calls).

```
    public void InsertNote(UnvoucheredInventoryNote note)
    {
        _db.UnvoucheredInventoryNotes.InsertOnSubmit(note);
    }

    public void Save()
    {
         _db.SubmitChanges();
    }
```

I have tried catching and re-throwing the exception in the `Save()` method, but it still fails and points the `throw` line in my `OnValidate` method.

What would cause this exception to halt at that line and not bubble up to my `catch` block in the Presentation layer?

Comment: Have you had a look at [How to: Break on User-Unhandled Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/038tzxdw.aspx)

Comment: @astander I answered my question below after yours and Reed's comments pointed me in the right direction.  Thank you!  Reed?  Your comment was perfectly valid... not sure why you removed it.  If either of you are willing to post the suggestion in the form of an answer, I will accept it rather than my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from Reed Copsey and Astander, I figured it out.  My debugger was set to break on User Unhandled Exceptions for `ApplicationException` and `System.Exception`.

The reason I did not catch this earlier is because I thought that "handling" them in a catch block in some way would override the first chance functionality, but apparently this is not the case.

Turning off the Break on Exception functionality allowed the Exception to bubble up to where I wanted it.

For Brevity here were the steps performed to do this:

1. Go to the Debug menu in VS
2. Click on 'Exceptions...'
3. Expand 'Common Language Runtime (CLR) Exceptions
4. Uncheck the type of Exception you **DO NOT** want to be caught by the First Chance debugger
5. Click OK